# How to properly rewrite ajax functions to Reactjs equivalents

Tags: ajax, reactjs

With Ajax/jquery Function code below I can get a particular user message  count and everything is working fine.

```
var userId='Nancy';

function handleUpdateCount(userId) {
  var count = (mCount[userId] == undefined) ? 1 : mCount[userId] + 1;
  mCount[userId] = count;
  $('#' + userId + ' label.mCount').html(count);
  $('#' + userId + ' label.mCount').show();

}
```

below is how I successfully display ajax result.

```
<label class="mCount"></label>
```

Now Am re-writting the above ajax/jquery code to work  with reactjs. So I have implemented the function below
which works fine in React as I can alert counter result in the **setState()** method.

```
handleUpdateCount = (userId) => {
const {mCount} = this.state;

     var count = mCount[userId] == undefined ? 1 : mCount[userId] + 1;
     mCount[userId] = count;


 this.setState({mCount: count});
// alert the result is working
 alert(this.state.mCount);

}
```

In the render method I knew I can get the result as per

```
{this.state.mcount && <label>{this.state.mcount}</label> }
```

**Here is my issue:**
How do I convert this two remaining ajax line of codes to reactjs equivalents.

```
$('#' + userId + ' label.mCount').html(count);
$('#' + userId + ' label.mCount').show();
```

Do I need to do something like code below in **reactjs** or what? since **userId** is involved that two lines of code above

```
if(userId){

 this.setState({mCount: count});
// alert the result is working
 alert(this.state.mCount);

}
```

**Updated Section**

The **userId** for either ajax or reactjs is coming from button click event

In Reactjs, you will have

```
<button
            onClick={() => this.handleUpdateCount(user.userId)}
          >{user.userId}</button>
```

**In Ajax, It is**

```
usersList += '<li id="' + user.id + '"  onclick="handleUpdateCount(this, \'' + user.id + '\')"><a href="javascript:void(0)">' + user.name + '101</a></li>';
```

Here is the css line of code called

```
.mCount { color: #FFF; float: right; border-radius: 12px; border: 1px solid #2E8E12; background: #34BB0C; padding: 2px 6px; }
```

**Below is full code of how am writting the ajax function to Reactjs equivalents**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
     mCount: {},
    };

 this.handleUpdateCount = this.handleUpdateCount.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {

 this.setState({

      data: [
        { userId: "nancy101", name: "Nancy Mooree", info: "Hello from Nancy"},
 { userId: "joy106", name: "Joy Mooree", info: "Hello from Joy"}
      ]
    });


  }



handleUpdateCount = (userId) => {
alert(userId);
const {mCount} = this.state;

     var count = mCount[userId] == undefined ? 1 : mCount[userId] + 1;
     mCount[userId] = count;

alert(count);

 this.setState({mssCount: count});
// alert the result is working
// alert(this.state.mssCount);

}





  render() {

    return (

          <div>
{this.state.mssCount}

{this.state.data.map((user, i) => {


if (user.userId !=='' && user.name !=='') {

          return (
            <div key={i}>
       <div>   
 {user.userId}: {user.name}

<br /><button
            onClick={() => this.handleUpdateCount(user.userId)}
          >{user.userId}</button>

            </div>
              </div>
          )


  } else {







  }
        })}



          </div>

    );
  }
```

Comment: It seems that in your old code you have an html element with an id so you grab and show the content inside. In react you don't need to have all those ids, just loop through your users and create and show and element based on available users.

Comment: Thanks for your contributions so far. Please Sir Hamed, can you provide me with a coding sample on how to go about with it.  Still struggling on getting it right

Comment: Sorry for my previous response. I think I did not get your question correctly. I can't see any userId in your old code: <label class="mCount"></label> I think I am missing a point here.

Comment: Please update your question so users can see your DOM structure.

Comment: Hello Sir Hamed, I have updated my post as you said. Please can you see the Updated section of my Post/Question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I foud out that this is the best way to create the function to achieve my goal. since am working with nodejs and socket.Io. I have found a way to emit users count along with the userId. The function below is still working perfect for me. Thanks

```
handleUpdateCount = (userId) => {
alert(userId);
const {mCount} = this.state;

     var count = mCount[userId] == undefined ? 1 : mCount[userId] + 1;
     mCount[userId] = count;
 this.setState({mssCount: count});

}
```